# call can throw , but it is not marked with "try" and error is not handled

Tags: swift3, try-catch, ios10

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    //get the values from sql/Json
    let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/dropdownmenu/phpGet.php")
    let data = Data(contentsOf: url! as URL)
    var tmpValues = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
    tmpValues = tmpValues.reversed() as NSArray
    reloadInputViews()

    for candidate in tmpValues {
    if let cdict = candidate as? NSDictionary {

            //fullName is the column name in sql/json

            let names = cdict["fullName"]
            self.values.append(names! as AnyObject)

        }
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZeQB.png)

Answer (score 14):

```
let optData = try? Data(contentsOf: url! as URL)
guard let data = optData else {
    return
}
```

Data(contentsOf: url! as URL) can throw an exception, you need to try the call.
By using let optData = try? ... you will have either a valid Data object or nil if an exception was thrown

Comment: Thank you , you save my time.

Comment: guard let jsonResponce = try? JSON(data: data) else {
                    failure("error")
                    return
                }